# How to police the number of parameters in a Makefile function

Tags: makefile, macros

I'd like to police a makefile function to ensure it is getting passed exactly three parameters.   (I want to protect against misquoted commas, etc)

What I had:

```
define foo
    $(if $(findstring $(origin 3)-$(origin 4),automatic-undefined,,$(error wrong parameter count))
    ...
endef
```

This seemed to work really well, but it recently came to my attention it can give a false negative:

```
define bar
    $(call foo,1,2,3)
endef
$(call bar,1,2,3,4)
```

will fail -- `$(origin $4)` (in the scope of `bar` *and* in the scope of `foo`), is now set to `automatic`.   This is because calling `bar,1,2,3,4` populates it, and the origin does not seem to change when `foo,1,2,3` is called...  (though the value does get cleared...)

So, now my question is is there a way to tell if a parameter was passed explicitly to the current function, or was set in a parent functions' context?

Comment: No, there's no way at the moment AFAIR.  I think there's a bug about this in Savannah but I didn't find it in a quick look.

Comment: As a "good-enough" approach, would `$(if $(if $(and $1,$2,$3),,t)$(findstring $(comma),$1$2$3)$4$5$6,$(error Wrong number or empty parameters))` be ok?

Comment: That's sort of what I ended up doing.   I checked that parameter 3 was automatic (paramter 3 must be specified, but can on occasion be blank, so I couldn't test for blank there), and then I tested if parameter 4 was blank.   It's not perfect but it will work in most cases.